# php editing record, how to include current id

Tags: php, mysql, edit

I am trying to add some functionality to my cooking book, but I can't think about a way of including the id I am clicking to edit.

The table is called "chefs", and the is 3 columns;
-id as auto_increment
- name
- country

Then, I have a list on index.php where I am displaying the chefs list:

```
<?php 
  $chefs = get_chefs();
?>

<h3>Chefs' list</h3>
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($chefs as $chef) {
      echo '<li>' . $chef['name'] . ' from ' . $chef['country'] . '<a class="toLink" href="edit_chef.php?id=' . $chef['id'] . '" title="edit chef">Edit chef</a>' . '</li>';  
    } ?>
</ul>
```

On functions php, I have a get_chefs() function and a find_chef_by_id($id) function:

```
function get_chefs() { 
   include'db_connection.php';
    try {
        return $conn->query("SELECT * FROM chefs");  
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error:' . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
        return array();
    }
    return true;
}

function find_chef_by_id($id = ':chef_id') {        
          include 'db_connection.php';

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM chefs WHERE id=:chef_id'; 

     try {
      $results = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $results->bindParam(':chef_id', $chef_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);    
      $results->execute();
     } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br />';
        return array();
    }
      return $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

To process the edition of a chef, I created a file called edit_chef.php:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $country = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'country', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(empty($name)) {
        $error_message = "Chef's name can not be empty";
    } elseif (empty($country)) {
        $error_message = "Country can not be empty";
    }else {
      if(edit_chef($name, $country)) {
         header('Location: index.php');
         exit;
      } else {
           $error_message = "Could not update chef";
      }
    }
}

include 'includes/header.php';?>
    <div class="col-container">
      <h1>Edit chef</h1>
      <?php
      if (isset($error_message)) {
          echo '<p class="message">' . $error_message . '</p>';
      }

      $chefs = get_chefs();
       foreach ($chefs as $chef) {
       $id = find_chef_by_id($chef["id"]);   


      ?>
      <form method="POST" action="edit_chef.php?chef=<?php echo urldecode($id); ?>">   
        <div>
          <label for="name" class="required">Name</label>
          <input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($chef["name"]); ?>" />
        </div>
         <div>
          <label for="country" class="required">Country</label>
          <input name="country" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($chef["country"]); ?>" />
        </div>
        <button class="submit" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

But at the moment, I don't know if it is because I shouldn't loop with foreach, or my $id value for the form shouldn't be find_chef_by_id($chef["id"]), when I click on Edit chef, it goes to the right url "http://localhost/cooking_book/edit_chef.php?id=1" but it appears a form for each of the chefs, not just the one I clicked.

What am I doing wrong??

Thank you

Comment: Should your 'find_chef_by_id' functions bindParam call be $id, not $chef_id?

Comment: Actually you are right, I've fixed that now, however, it makes no change at all, still, when I click to edit chef appears a form for each one there are in the dable

Comment: also you should not need the 'foreach ($chefs as $chef) {' inside your edit_chef.php

Comment: Sec i'll provide a better answer with code examples.

Comment: Yes, I can see that, that's why I have a for for each record but..... how to I get the id for the chef I just clicked to edit?

Comment: this `$id = find_chef_by_id($chef["id"])` should be smth like `$id = find_chef_by_id($_GET['id'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First mistake is having $chef_id instead of $id in your find_chef_by_id function, you need to fix that.

The other thing is, i do not understand why you need to loop around all chefs in your database if you already know the ID thats passed via the address?

For example:
In your edit_chef.php you need to capture the GET data:

```
<?php

    //Get the ID from the URL
    $chefID = null;
    if ( isset($_GET['id']) )
        $chefID = $_GET['id'];

    if ( $chefID == null )
        die ( "oops, Chef ID is null, bad request?" );

    //Now find the chef we need
    $theChef = find_chef_by_id($chefId);   

    //do stuff

?>
```

That should be all you need to fix.

Also in your form add a hidden text field that echo's out the current ID that you obtained via the GET request:

```
<input type="hidden" name="chefId" value="<?=$chefId?>">
```

Using this method you're able to pull the chef ID from the POST data next time the user presses the Submit button on the edit form, so you do not need a custom Action="blah" on the form inside chef_edit.php

Comment: Oh also, as your dealing with URL based data (id in this case) you need error handling on the find_chef_by_id function, for example if i pass edit_chef.php?id=TheCakeIsALie, there most likely is not a ID of 'TheCakeIsALie' in your database (let alone it not being a number).

Instead of returning $results->fetchAll in that function, instead see if the amount of rows is zero, if it is return NULL, otherwise return the fetchAll data - then you can check for null later and error out.

Comment: If you need any more help feel free to join the PHP Chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php where lots of people including myself are ready to tackle your questions :)

Comment: ok... ok give me a sec that I process all this and I get back to you! Are here php chat rooms? :o I will definitely join :) 

Thank you!!

Comment: Mark! I will join the php chat now, but just for not repeating all again, on the form on edit_page.php, I add  $theChef = find_chef_by_id($chefId);  , but then, why does it display an error:  saying that Undefined index: name and Undefined index: country on the form values? If I print_r($theChef) it prints this: 1Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => chef1 [country] => spain ) ) , so why I can't put them into the value of the form to be edited?

Comment: great.... change the question; why does it have to be $theChef[0]['country'] instead of just $theChef['country'] ?

Comment: fetchAll will return an array of objects that the SQL statement query returns. -- For example if there are 3 elements that the SQL Query will return, the fetchAll will return an array sizeof 3. -- however if you instead use just fetch instead of fetchAll, it will only return the singular entry, thus not needing the [0]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127809/discussion-between-mark-phillips-and-eve-mf).

Comment: I am very sorry Mark Phillips! I had a busy time at work and I left the site.... But I am still having trouble with it, I don't know what I am doing wrong and it is so frustrating..... I will go in the chat room, hopefully you are still there!

Comment: you aren't there anymore :( I am finishing work in 30 min but if you are around tomorrow.... and you can give me a shout... please please please

Comment: just to let you know, I have fixed, eventually ^^, I didn't removed the id from the url of the form action..... even if you said it!

Thanks :)

Comment: Hey that's great - Sorry i was not around afterwards.